# Why we need $\min_{1\leq i \leq v} (t_i - t_{i-1}) > \delta$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence

Let $D[0,1]$ be ta space of real functions $f$ on $[0,1]$ that are right continuous and have left limit. That is space of *cadlag* functions.

Now for $f\in D$ and $T\subset [0,1]$, define $$w_f(T) = \sup_{s,t\in T} |f(s) -f(t)|.$$ If we consider space of continuous functions then this is nothing but *modulus of continuity*. But in $D$, it is not.

In $D$, we consider $0 =t_0 <...<t_v=1$ points such that $\min_{i=1,...,v} (t_i - t_{i-1}) > \delta $. This called $\delta$-sparsed condition. Then modulus of continuity defined in D as
$$w'_f(\delta) = \inf_{\{t_i\}} \max_{i=1,...,v} w_f([t_{i-1}, t_i)).$$

Where infimum taken over all $\delta$- sparse ${\{t_i\}}$ partition of [0,1].

My question is, **why we need $\delta$- sparsity to define modulus of continuity in $D$?**

Comment: Neither one is a modulus of continuity as defined on the wikipedia page you almost link to (please fix the address in your link). There, the modulus of continuity dominates the ratio of $|f(x) - f(y)|$ to $|x - y|$. Here you are merely dominating $|f(x) - f(y)|$ itself.

Comment: @PaulSinclair okay, let's use my definition, what I defined in the problem.

Comment: You can define whatever you want, so you can certainly drop the $\delta$ from the definition if you want. However, the question is whether the thing one defines is *useful*, e.g., in theorems.

Comment: "Modulus of continuity" is a useful functional to characterize uniformly equicontinuous families. Uniformly Equicontinuous families are useful subsets because they are precompact under a further uniform boundness assumption (Arzelà-Ascoli Theorem). This is, as a result, quite useful to establish convergence of sequences in the functional space of discussion. By choosing the (finite $\delta$-partition) in the "inf" to sit at the discontinuity instants, you get $\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0} \sup_{f\in D} \omega_f'(\delta)=0$ which characterizes precompact families in the Skorokhod space.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen is this so? How do I know the thing is *useful* or not? What is the motivation behind that?